# Python Cannot Find Firefox Webdriver in Kali Linux Selenium Directory

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox, geckodriver, kali-linux

Running the simple test code below in Kali Linux gives the error

`"ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver'":`

Code:

```
root@notdisclosed:/usr/local# python
>>>from selenium import webdriver
```

I am using Selenium 3.141.0, Firefox 73.0.1, and Geckodriver 0.25.0. 
Full error log below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from .firefox.webdriver import WebDriver as Firefox  # noqa
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver'
```

Not sure if I have all dependencies stored in the proper directories. I have tried different versions of geckodriver and firefox with no success. Really no idea what the issue is, any insight would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There was an incompatibility issue with Firefox and Geckodriver. Downgraded Firefox to 64.0.2 and upgraded Geckodriver to 0.26.0 for a successful combination.